# Symfony forms & handling Doctrine constraint violations gracefully

Tags: php, forms, validation, doctrine

I have built a form using symfony's form builder to create new entries with the doctrine entity manager, but upon creating new entries, I occasionally run into a `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry'`. I would like to properly handle this exception using the DRY principles, what is the best way to do this gracefully?

Preferably I would have a warning show even before submitting but after submission would be acceptable also.

FlightController.php

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/new", name="flight_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request)
{
  //Create New Flight
  $flight = new Flight($this->getDoctrine()->getManager());
  $form = $this->createForm(FlightType::class, $flight);

  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $flight = $form->getData();

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($flight);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute("flight_list");

  }
  return $this->render('flight/new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Flight.php The constraint is a compound key:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FlightRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="flight",
 *      uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="flight",columns={"ap_from","ap_to"})}
 * )
 */
class Flight
{
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create custom validator and check uniqueness. Also `UniqueConstraint` can be used.

Comment: Custom validator is the way to go. You could also add an AJAX action to warn beforehand for a slightly better UX.

Comment: What would be a good way to integrate a clean AJAX action in the process?